# MessageLockLostException breaks Service Bus QueueClient

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have service which listens to Service Bus Queue. Once in a few days I receive `MessageLockLostException`. Exception itself is clear for me and that's not an issue. However QueueClient seems broken after exception received and stops processing any further messages. I understand that i can add `try / catch` to `ProcessMessagesAsync`. However I thought that `ExceptionReceivedHandler` should handle such cases and QueueClient should try to process same message again(or send it to DLQ if it fails to process it multiple time).

```
public class QueueService
{
    private readonly QueueClient _queueClient;

    public QueueServiceServiceBus(string connectionString, ILogger<QueueServiceServiceBus> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        var serviceBusConnectionStringBuilder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
        _queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionStringBuilder);

        RegisterMessageHandler();
    }

    private Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Message handler encountered an exception {Exception}",
            exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }        

    private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        //Handle message

        await _queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }

    private void RegisterMessageHandler()
    {
        var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            AutoComplete = false
        };

        _queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExceptionReceivedHandler` handles the exceptions which occurs during the retrieval  and processing of the messages.

The `QueueClient` will not break for any reason unless it gets throttled with over load.

I tried the sample what you provided. It works fine for me, the `ExceptionReceivedHandler` handles the `MessageLockLostException` without breaking.

Comment: Even if exceptions get's logged by this line? ` _logger.LogError("Message handler encountered an exception {Exception}",
            exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception);`

Comment: I have modified my answer, ExceptionReceivedHandler handles the exceptions which occurs while processing the messages.